# Override spring boot dependency version with gradle kotlin-dsl

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

SpringBoot comes with a lot of dependencies plus default versions for them.
In groovy-gradle, such dependency versions can be overridden with:

```
ext['mockito.version'] = '1.7.5'
```

But this doesn't work for the kotlin-dsl.
I tried:

```
val mockito by extra { "2.12.0" }
val mockito.version by extra { "2.12.0" }
val `mockito.version` by extra { "2.12.0" }
```

The latter two, don't compile, the first one, isn't doing the job.

How can the version be overridden within the kotlin file (I don't want to create a separate properties file if it is somehow possible).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `extra["mockito.version"] = "1.7.5"`